# Switching from Outlook to Gsuite: saving emails to folders & working with them

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, google-workspace

My wife's company recently switched over to Gsuite from Outlook.

When in Outlook, she used to save emails (.eml files) in shared folders for the rest of her team to work with. She would often click on one of these .eml files, which would launch Outlook, and from there she would be able to work - reply, forward, etc.

Now they've switched to Gsuite, and she has trouble re-creating this workflow: emails can be exported from Gmail, but opening them from a shared folder is a hassle. They open by default in Outlook (now blocked by her company). I've tried setting Google Chrome as her default program for emails, but it does just that: it opens the email *in Chrome*, not *in Gmail* (= impossible to reply/forward/...).

.eml files saved to Google Drive do not open in Gmail either.

She needs multiple collaborators to save emails to common folders, and she also needs each of them to be able to read/reply/forward any email saved to these folders.

What do you suggest?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Gmail and Outlook work differently on this matter but there are few ways in order to achieve what you are looking for.

First thing first, it depends in which G Suite Edition is your account, manly because of the Storage space.

G Suite Basic: 30Gb per user
G Suite Business: 1-4 User 1TB per user. 5 user up Unlimited Storage.

Compare G Suite Editions: https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_ph/compare-editions/

Now in G suite there isn’t such a thing like a default ‘Archive’ for the emails as in Outlook. All the email are store into the User Cloud Storage and there they stay, because you don’t have a fixed device but rather your device is in a Google Server (Cloud) . But by knowing this you can work around it.

For instance if you G Suite Basic, you can create a new User that has 30Gb of cloud Storage and you use this User as a “Back UP,” you can do it the same with a G Suite Business.

Then you can delegate your account (or the back up account) to other users, see ---> Set up mail delegation: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350

At the end of the day you will have a consistent backup of your email and if you need to access them you just log in with this user (as delegate or not)

Having said that, there is a way to Download the email into a folder into your Device with a PST file , either with GSSMO or GSMME,althouhg they one Uses Outlook:

G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook, Import your data (you can also export it): https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/153874?hl=en
G Suite Migration for Microsoft Exchange, Migrate data from PST files: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7364501?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your reply Federico. However I don't think either solutions you suggested will do.
1 - creating a new account and setting up mail delegation: up to the IT department and not something they'll likely do. This is a big company.
2 - importing/exporting emails: unwieldy and, as you said, requires Outlook at some point, thus breaking the desired workflow.
Thanks for your suggestions though.